# How to turn visiblity of a java gui window on and off by a single button?

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I'm writing down a small gui program which consists of two windows, one is dummy "tv" and and 2nd one is "remote"

i want to set the visibility of tv window on and off by a single button on remote button, and i was thinking that i can do it by this way

```
private class gbm implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        tv obj = new tv();

        if(obj.setVisible(true))
        {
            obj.setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            obj.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

but i'm having error that it's incompatible type , bollean required and it's void, my first if condition i'm talking about.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if TV is visible, you should be using

`if(tv.isVisible()) { //blah }`

That being said, you shouldn't be creating a new `tv` every time the button is pressed. You should pass the tv to the `ActionListener` as a final.

Comment: i created the tv object in main remote class and problem is solved ..
thank you